# What SQL query should I use to change post date to another date?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have 7000+ posts published on October 31, 2021. What SQL should I use to change the date for all those posts to Feb 1, 2022?

I run a WordPress site with MySQL 5.7.37 and PHP 7.4.

Honestly, I have no idea of anything.

Any help to change the date in bulk for thousands of posts at once will be much appreciated.

Looking forward to some help from experts!

Comment: Something like `UPDATE post_table SET date_field = '2022-02-01' WHERE date_field = '2021-10-31';` Would likely do the trick. Before you run something like an UPDATE which is not reversible, test the WHERE criteria using a SELECT `SELECT * FROM post_table WHERE date_field = '2021-10-31';`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM post_table WHERE date_field = '2021-10-31'; is not returning any rows.

Comment: Sorry. I just made up the table name and column name. I'm not terribly familiar with wordpress. Might be something like `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_date = '2021-10-31'`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to update post date from your theme / plugin's code then you can use `$wpdb` to run the SQL command. Something like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->query( "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_date = '2022-02-01 00:00:00' WHERE post_date LIKE '2021-10-31%'");
```

**Note:** `$wpdb->posts` returns the name of your post table dynamically so you don't have to remember the post table name.

If you're going to use the command directly from `phpmyadmin` then just use

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET `post_date` = '2022-02-01 00:00:00' WHERE `post_date` LIKE '2021-10-31%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as already mentioned in comments.

```
UPDATE posts SET post_date = '2022-02-01' WHERE post_date = '2021-10-31';
```

Double-check the post_date format first though, as it may be in long number format etc.

Comment: Did not work. :(

Comment: @user2513375 ensure that "posts" is replaced with the correct table name for your posts, and "post_date" is replaced with the correct column name for your post dates. Also check the format of your posts' dates. If you still haven't fixed it, post some sample data and the column + table names and I'll write a query for you